# Why do Phobia exist if they aren't advantageous?

Tags: entomology, arachnology

A phobia is usually the irrational fear of something, and the individual experiencing it is often unable to justify whether there is such detestation of something which might not even be threatening.

I am aware that there are:

- *Agoraphobia*
- *Social Phobia*
- *Specific Phobias* such as *Arachnophobia* (fear of spiders) or *Ophidiophobia* (fear of snakes)

**My question** **is**, *why do some people have e.g. Arachnophobia but not something closely related such as Entomophobia (fear of insects)? 
And why do phobias even exist at all? To me they don't seem to serve a purpose (protection), and do not seem to be of advantageous existence.
Furthermore, I am curious to why exactly a phobia exists – and in some cases manages to be  passed on from the parent to the offspring.*

**DISCLAIMER:**

I am aware of there being several psychological processes involved in this such as events that occurred in early years, or if there is a relative with anxiety, the risk of you suffering of a phobia is significantly larger. I also heard there is a high incidence of people developing phobias after traumatic brain injuries.

However, I am interested in the biological aspect of a phobia, and that why if it isn't advantageous to us, why does it exist?

Comment: Why do you say that there aren't people with a phobia of insects in general? Can you support that claim? Also, not everything that exists has advantages. Lots of non-advantageous things exist. Phobias, for example are maladaptive. Fear, on the other hand, is often adaptive.

Answer (score 1):

I think the fault in your reasoning is the assumption that phobias are not advantageous to us. As an example of a potentially useful phobia, consider the fear of heights. Now consider two different ancestors: one who was afraid of heights and one who was not. Generally speaking, the ancestor who was afraid of heights would likely avoid such environments and thereby reduce the likelihood of, say, falling off a cliff or high precipice. In evolutionary terms, we would say that natural selection confers an advantage to the phobia-possessing individual(s). [This](http://serendip.brynmawr.edu/bb/neuro/neuro02/web3/mwhite.html) website in particular has some interesting reading:

> Others believe that phobias exist because of evolutionary development to avoid danger in order to improve survival. There are several stimuli that are shared by the most phobic people (heights, insects, crowds, etc.) These phobias, with a couple of exceptions, relate more closely to pre-technological societies. Thus, some scientists, such as Martin Seligman, believe that people are inherently "prepared" to fear certain objects. ((5))) In other words, our phobias relate closely to the perils of our ancestors, as through natural selection, those who feared the dangerous stimulus survived while those who didn't, died off. Prepared fears appear to be very easily conditioned. Some scientists, such as LeDoux, believe that preparedness and the ease of conditioning are the result of certain preexisting neurological connections that exist evolutionarily. These connections are turned on with relative ease.

Comment: I get your point and appreciate the example, however I am still curious as to why someone could be a sufferer from Arachnophobia but not Entomophobia? Both could be seen to have similar features, would you not agree that it is odd, to see someone having a phobia of something, but not of something which is closely related to the other angst. I'd be very grateful, if you could provide me with some resources/informations on that.

Comment: I think there is a difference between rational and irrational fear. Irrational fear is not advantageous; rational fear is. A fear of heights is rational; a phobia is not. A phobia is something that actively disrupts someone's life.

Comment: @anongoodnurse: Why is a fear of heights (or of anything) advantageous?  As opposed to sensible caution, of course.  From what I've seen, it actually makes injury more likely, as the phobic person either freezes, or runs in panic.

Comment: Okay, so I see the distinction now, sorry that I was unable to answer that in my post. @jamesqf Per the definitions we are using, "rational fear" would certainly be advantageous if it leads to avoidance of the risky/dangerous/fear-inducing situation to begin with. So as I pointed out in my fear of heights example (which imo is a rational fear), the person would avoid precarious and elevated scenarios altogether. Granted, this may be a disadvantage if the person needs (for some reason) to be in such a location. For most of the part, though, it would prove advantageous.